# Deep learning for inferences in sequences

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, hidden-markov-models, unsupervised-learning

I want to use deep learning techniques to perform better inference tasks than Hidden Markov Models (which is a shallow model)? I was wondering what is the state-of-the art deep learning model to replace Hidden Markov Models (HMM)? The set-up is semi-supervised. The training data X(t),Y(t) is a time series, with significant temporal correlations. Also, there is a huge amount of unlabelled data, i.e., simply X(t) and no Y(t). After reading many papers, I narrowed down on the following model -> Conditionally Restricted Boltzmann Machines (Ilya Sustkever MS thesis) and use Deep Belief Networks for unsupervised pretraining (or use variational autoencoders for pretraining). I am very new to the field, and was wondering if these techniques are outdated.

Comment: This higher level of question belongs on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/); SO is more for specific programming problems.

Comment: I'd also argue that this is two or three questions in one.  @rahuls88, if you want to increase your chances of someone answering your question, then break questions into separate posts.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I was wondering what is the state-of-the art deep learning model to replace Hidden Markov Models (HMM)"

At the moment RNN (Recurrent Neural Network) and LSTM (Long Short Term Memory) based DNNs are state of the art. They are the best for a lot of sequencing problems starting from Named Entity Recognition (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-Named-Entity-Recognition-NER/answer/Rahul-Vadaga),  Parsing (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00874.pdf) to Machine Translation (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08144.pdf).
These DNNs are also called sequence models (e.g. seq2seq where input as well as output is a sequence like Machine Translation)

"unsupervised pretraining"

The pre-training is not that popular any more (for supervised ML problems) since you can achieve the same results using random restarts with parallelization as you have more (and cheaper) CPUs now.

[Added the following later]

A recent paper (Optimal Hyperparameters for Deep LSTM-Networks for Sequence Labeling Tasks
by Nils Reimers, and Iryna Gurevych) does a good comparison of various seq2seq for common NLP tasks: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06799.pdf

Definitely worth a read.

Comment: @Abhimanu..great...I was going to try pretraining, but now I will try random restarts

Comment: @Abhimanu....what would be a good reference for sequence to sequence machine models? I have read Alex Graves' thesis, and it seemed good introducetion. But its written in 2007, seems pretty old.

Comment: Start from a code base that implements a seq2seq. I would say Tensorflow is a good codebase to start: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq . And also read related papers (Google Machine Translation papers are a good start).

Comment: thanks a lot for the reference. This should be a good starting point. However, one more issue is that there is no supervised data, i.e., the "hidden sequence X(t)" is never revealed. The sequence to sequence models (or most of the Deep Learning algorithms) use some form of gradient descent, to minimize the "loss". Since loss can only be generated if the algorithm has access to labels (in this case X(t)), I guess I might have to resort to HMM (Baum Welch algorithm) to generate labels, and then train the LSTM. Is this a good idea?

Comment: unsupervised sequence learning using DNN is an active area of research with no big breakthroughs yet unlike the supervised case. Start from here ftp://ftp.idsia.ch/pub/juergen/icann2001unsup.pdf (Schmidhuber's group first came up with the LSTMs that are popular now).  

For semi-supervised you can start with whatever labeled data you have in the LSTM/RNN/GRU based DNN, predict next set of unlabled examples and loop them in the training set in the next batch. Do this iteratively.

Comment: looks good. I will follow the Juergen paper. Also I had a doubt about the comment on training procedure for semisupervised learning  "For semi-supervised you can start with whatever labeled data you have in the LSTM/RNN/GRU based DNN, predict next set of unlabled examples and loop them in the training set in the next batch."
Do you mean that if a labelled sequence (X(t),Y(t))_{t=1,2,...,T} is given, then
1. try to generate a sequence \hat{X}(t) (by using an LSTM predictor that has been trained using the labelled example)
2. Now use \hat{X}(t),Y(t) as a data point an improve the LSTM weights

Comment: I guess you were referring to this paper http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5949-semi-supervised-sequence-learning.pdf ?